# generate random six character base 36 string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to generate a random six character base 36 string.

I am using below two packages, but it not always returning the six characters.

```
const seed = require('random-seed').create();
const bases = require('bases')
console.log(bases.toBase36(seed(10000000, 99999999)))
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/random-seed) is quite clear about how `random-seed` works. There's no "default" version that accepts two arguments. You want `.intBetween(min, max)` instead. `seed(10000000, 99999999)` generates a random number between `0` and `10000000`. `99999999` is ignored.

Comment: And `seed` is a terrible name for a random number generator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to generate a random number between two values in base36, I'd suggest passing these two limits to the random number generator.

The [intBetween](https://www.npmjs.com/package/random-seed#randintbetweenmin-max) function will return a value defined by min, max (inclusive), so we can pass the minimum numeric values specified by our base36 range:

```
const rand = require('random-seed').create();
const bases = require('bases')

const minValue = bases.fromBase36('100000');
const maxValue = bases.fromBase36('zzzzzz');

console.log(bases.toBase36(rand.intBetween(minValue, maxValue)))
```

You'll see values generated like this:

```
p0ybas
w3y59y
sokk89
shr876
40exwf
4cvk9i
6t4h44
givwox
```

Comment: As it is mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/random-seed)...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest I've tried is:

```js
randstr = _ => Math.floor(2176782335*Math.random()).toString(36);
randstr();
```

or easier to remember:

```js
randstr = _ => Math.floor(parseInt('zzzzzz',36)*Math.random()).toString(36);
randstr();
```

This is taking the Base36 value `zzzzzz`; multiplying by 0 ≤ n ≤ 1 to get a value between `000000` and `zzzzzz`; and then converting back to Base36.

More generally:

```js
randstr = len => (
  Math.floor(Math.pow(36,len)*Math.random())
      .toString(36)
);
randstr(6);
```

About 2% of the time, these solutions may give strings shorter than `len`, due to leading zeroes.  If that matters:

```js
randstr = len => (
  Math.floor(Math.pow(36,len)*(1+Math.random()))
      .toString(36)
      .slice(-len)
);
randstr(6);
```

Saying all that, while it's more fun to do wacky things like:

```js
randstr => len => (
  '1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm'
    .repeat(len)
    .split('')
    .sort( _ => Math.random()-.5 )
    .join('')
    .slice(-len)
);
randstr(6);
```

it's incredibly slow.

Disappointingly, it's quicker and clearer to ignore the math approach and just do it with strings:

```js
randstr = len => {
  let x = '';
  while (len--)
    x += '1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm'[Math.floor(36*Math.random())];
  return x;
};
randstr(6);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like this to get random characters

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
console.log(crypto.randomBytes(36).toString('hex'));
```

`crypto` is Built-in in NodeJs